# no colorama colors when called from gradle process

Tags: python, gradle, colorama

I have a python [cli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) program that uses colorama. It is working fine when directly launched from windows cmd shell or from cygwin shell using "python foo.py".
However, when I call the program from another process ([gradle exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) in my case), the colors are gone.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Do the colors work if you pass `convert=False` to the `colorama.init()` call? Just wondering if it is similar to [this issue in PyCharm](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/107)

Comment: @FrenAndr, I tried with convert=False and it did not help. Now it does not print with colors everywhere (shell and gradle)